# Join rows of a specific column of a table-A using table-B where the value of column in the table-A is zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Table-A

```
X
1
0
0
5
7
0
0
```

Table-B

```
X
1.2
5.1
8.9
22
24
99.8
15.5
```

The output I expect

```
 X
 1
 5.1
 8.9
 5
 7
 99.8
 15.5
```

The values of Table-B are copied to Table-A where the Table-A values are zero

Comment: The only way I can make sense of this question is by lining up the tables by row.  But tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering.  You need to be clearer in your question on what drives the logic.

Comment: You've tagged both 2008 & 2012 - you should only tag the version you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

SQL table represent *unordered* sets of rows. For what you want to be doable, you need an ordering column in each of the tables.

Assuming that these exist and are called `id`, you can use `row_number()` to align the rows across the tables, and a `case` expression for prioritization:

```
select case when a.x = 0 then b.x else a.x end x
from (select row_number() over(order by id) rn, x from tablea) a
left join (select row_number() over(order by id) rn, x from tableb) b 
    on a.rn = b.rn
```